# MDX: Dynamically generate fiscal years range

Tags: database, ssas, mdx, olap

I have date parameter like

```
[Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].[Year].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
```

that shows when client's fiscal year starts. So month and year can be changed.

Depending on this I need to create query that will calculate linear regression (LinRegPoint function) by fiscal years. The problem is in cube's FiscalYear dates, they have fixed start month.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Average Fees Per Copy] AS 
    LinRegPoint
    (
      Rank
      (
        [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].CurrentMember
       ,[Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].[Year].MEMBERS
      )
     ,[Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].[Year]
     ,
      [Measures].[Spend] / [Measures].[Copies]
     ,Rank
      (
        [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].CurrentMember
       ,[Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Date].[Year].MEMBERS
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Average Fees Per Copy]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Time].[Year].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [spend];
```

Here is my query, it calculates predicted values and based on cube's Fiscal Years values (that always starts on 6-th month). But how to cut cube's years on years which starts from my month in given parameter and then find linregpoint value for current client's fiscal year where calculation will be based on this cut values?

Comment: can you just add a Fiscal Year dimension into the cube?

Comment: @whytheq Even if I add Fiscal Year dimension into the cube it will have fixed begin year value like "1 january". But I need ability to change this begin value depending on input parameter (it may depends on client that login into system and run the query). Every client may have different FiscalYear begin month.

But it can be nice solution if I could just change cube's FiscalYear begin month (now I think it needs to reprocess whole cube to achieve this).

Comment: How are you capturing this begin month for the client's fiscal year?

Comment: @whytheq we store it in relational DB and for MDX query we using parameter like 'currentYearNumber-fiscalMonthNumber-01T00:00:00' that completly enters in query through strtomember function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I didn't found solution for slicing time axis in query according to given year start date, so I use a workaround for this problem.

The main idea is to create custom date\time dimension and link it through many-to-many table to calendar dimension. This calendar table should store all calendars with different start year date. So your SSAS datasource may be simillar to something like this:

[SSAS DSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv16O.png)

Then you just create measure from M2M table and use it in dimensions with date attributes with M2M relationship.

To not to store all calendar-specific data in relational DB you can imrove this solution by creating views that will calculate all on request so all this data will exists only in SSAS.

You can find more info here:

https://elonblackman.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/handling-multiple-time-calendars-in-a-many-to-many-ssas-scenario/